# GWT - Animate a com.google.gwt.visualization.client.visualizations.corechart

Tags: gwt

I am trying to set animation on a ColumnChart but there is no method in com.google.gwt.visualization.client.visualizations.corechart.Options to do so.

Apparently calling the following function does not work either:  options.set("animation.duration", new Double(1000));

Has anyone managed to animate a corechart through GWT ?

Thanks for your help !

Hugues

==> Just found the answer myself. If anyone is interested the code is below. The idea is to extend the class com.google.gwt.visualization.client.visualizations.corechart.Options

```
import com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptObject;

public class MyOptions extends com.google.gwt.visualization.client.visualizations.corechart.Options {

 protected MyOptions() {
  }
 public final native void setAnimationDuration(double animationDuration) /*-{
    this.animation={
    duration: animationDuration,
    easing: 'out',
  }
 }-*/;

     public static MyOptions create() {
            return JavaScriptObject.createObject().cast();
          }
```

}

Comment: actually you don't have to rely on a native final function to achieve that. You could just create a animation ``Option`` instance and then set the the parameters (animationDUration, easing) there with ``option.set()``. Finally you add the animation option instance to your root option instance. Something like that:  ``rootOption.set('animation',animationOption)``

Answer (score 1):

That is incorrect form. You need to use smthing like this:

```
    private Options createOptions() 
    {
        Options option = Options.create();     

        Properties animation = Properties.create();
        animation.set("duration", 1000.0);
        animation.set("easing", "out");
        option.set("animation", animation);

        //return options;       
        return option;       
    }
```

it's answer for the future. You can see more details from [acra-reporter](http://code.google.com/p/acra-reporter/source/browse/trunk/src/nz/org/winters/appspot/acrareporter/client/ui/Overview.java?spec=svn24&r=24.)
Unfortunately at this moment it doesn't work on a piechart and I'm tring to solve this problem

Comment: It would be nice if you can add more explanation to why is it better.